# AsyncTask result onPostExecute is null

Tags: java, android-asynctask

I'm trying to show Parse.com objects on listView.
I'm doing a and it returns objects to the ListArray, but on onPostExecute the result is null and therefore not showing on listview.
Tried just adding some strings to the ArrayList onPostExecute to see if it will work if the ArrayList was not null and it works...
Can someone guide me on how to do this?
Thanks.

```
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();

    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<>("CashFlow");
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        for (ParseObject parseObject : objects) {
                            String task;
                            task = (String) parseObject.get("title");
                            data.add(task);

                        }
                    } else {
                        // Something went wrong.
                    }
                }
            });
            return data;
        }catch (Exception e){
            return null;
        }


    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
        if (result != null) {
            CustomUsersAdapter adapter = new CustomUsersAdapter(getApplicationContext(), result);
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvUsers);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you are getting result at do in background. put a debug pointer (at return data) their first and observer what you are getting there.

Comment: You are starting two threads, your AsyncTask returns before your ParseQuery. That's why the result is null. Both run in another thread as it seems. You don't actually need the AsyncTask. Put your onPostExecute stuff in the done method, remove the AsyncTask and it should work. If the callback is not on the UI thread, use a Handler or Activity.runOnUIThread()...